# Calculate days of month

Tags: vb.net

Is there any method for calculating the number of days in a month?

Comment: Actually, it's closer to 30.436875, on average. There are ((365*3+366)*25-1)*4+1, or 146,097 days in 400 years.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes:

```
Const July As Integer = 7
Const Feb As Integer = 2

' daysInJuly gets 31. '
Dim daysInJuly As Integer = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(2001, July)

' daysInFeb gets 28 because the year 1998 was not a leap year. '
Dim daysInFeb As Integer = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(1998, Feb)

' daysInFebLeap gets 29 because the year 1996 was a leap year. '
Dim daysInFebLeap As Integer = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(1996, Feb)
```

Credit goes to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx).

Comment: If you are looking for the number of days, this works. If you are looking for a list of days, then use my example below.

Answer (score 0):

http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/sys/DateTimeClassDaysInMonth.aspx

```
Public Shared Function DaysInMonth ( _
   ByVal year As Integer, _
   ByVal month As Integer _
} As Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim d As New DateTime(2010, 4, 1)

Dim month As Integer = d.Month

While d.Month = month
    Console.WriteLine(d.[Date])
    d = d.AddDays(1)
End While
```

You can of course change how you output the Date to format it to your will.

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of days of current month

```
Dim CurrentMonthDays As Int16 = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year,DateTime.Now.Month)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use an array:  [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
Add one to Feb if (year mod 400 = 0) or ( (year mod 4 = 0) and not (year mod 100 = 0) )

Answer (score -2):

You have two simple solutions:

```
5546>>m&1|30^(m==2)*2+(m==2&&y%4==0)))
```

or

```
(62648012>>m*2&3)+28+(m==2&&y%4==0)))
```

where m is the number of month and y is the year.

this solution is the same below, an array, but the array is bit masked in magic numbers.